# Android:Styling ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-styles

I want to put some style in the ListView in such a way that when an item of ListView is hovered, the color of that list item changes. I dont have any idea about how to achieve this.

Please suggest some other ideas about styling the ListView as well.

Regards,

Comment: See these links: (1) http://www.hambonious.com/2010/06/customizing-android-listview-colors.html (2) http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/android-changing-listview-background-colors.......... I hope this may help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051297/how-do-i-style-selected-item-in-android-listview

Comment: you can do it dynamically if you are using custom adapter for your listview. In your getview method you will be inflating the view. There you can set background color whatever you want. May be it will help you.

Comment: Hi,
Can you give a sample code for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selector to define what should happen when you focus the item, select the item and press the item, I doubt you cannot hover over a view, since Android devices use touch screen interface and not a pointing interface like a mouse..

This should help you:

Create a XML file in drawable folder named listselector.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

Then set the background of your `TextView` which you use in `ListView` to this like

`android:background = "@drawable/listselector"`,

that should do it.

Comment: Hi,

I am getting this compilation error message:

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/blue'). listselector.xml

Please help

Comment: Create a new XML file called colors in values folder in your project add HTML color codes for blue green and white into that XML file like this <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
<color name="blue">#0000ff</color> and all the other colors you want and reference it back using android:drawable="@color/blue" in listselector.xml file

Comment: ListView does not contains any TextView, i am binding the items of Listview using a List. 

This is the code for my ListView:

<ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:background = "@drawable/listselector">

TheListView background is red and focus is not working, on clicking it becomes blue for a moment and again becomes red

Comment: This is my color.xml:


Colors.xml:
    
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color> 
    <color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
    <color name="white">#000000</color>

Comment: use TextView in separate xml file and inflate it as a row in your ListView see this example for more http://www.technotalkative.com/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-2-custom-listview/