# Android: Changing color of text in ListView without custom adapter

Tags: android-layout

Is it possible to change textColor in ListView without defining custom adapter for it? As in TextView we can apply style = "@style/mystyle" in which we can define textcolor.

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview" 
    style="@style/WhiteText"
    />
```

In values, the style is defined as:

```
    <resources>
    <style name= "WhiteText">
    <item name ="android:textColor">#FFFFFF </item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000 </item>
    </resources>
```

I tried it but it's not giving me desired output. So I want to ask, is it a valid way or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be possible with to define the style for the ListView and set the Text color for that.

See below SO Answer:

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558172/apply-style-to-android-listview)

[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051297/how-do-i-style-selected-item-in-android-listview)

Hope it will help you.
 If any query then let me know.

Comment: In both the SO answers, custom ListView is used. I just want to change the textColor of ListView so I wonder is there any way to do it easily without using custom listadapter?

Comment: @SternBravo: you can only do it with style of the list view